# K-ring of splittable bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Is there something non-trivial to be said about the subring of $K(X)$ spanned by one-dimensional bundles?

If I am not mistaken, it is still a functor into commutative rings from the category of schemes. Moreover, it seems that there is some [interest](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Emahrud/oral/exposition.pdf) in the splitting problem for vector bundles, which goes back to Grothendieck's result that for $\mathbb{P}^1$ all bundles split. Also, by the splitting principle, any element of $K(X)$ lands in such a subring after a suitable pullback.

But maybe my question is stupid for some obvious reason.

Edit: Some concrete questions:

1. Is the existence of an indecomposable bundle on $X$ imply that the subring generated by line bundles is proper?
2. Is there an analog of higher $K$-groups for this definition? (I don't see any problem with taking the usual motivic construction, but what do I know)
3. Are there known computations of this ring?
4. Is there a general relationship between the usual $K$-ring and this subring?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by "something non-trivial".

Comment: @Sasha, Thank you! I added some concrete questions I had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

No for question 1.

Indeed, $K(\mathbb{P}^2)$ is generated by line bundles (in fact, it is freely generated by $\mathcal{O}$, $\mathcal{O}(1)$, $\mathcal{O}(2)$), but there are plenty of indecomposable vector bundles (e.g., the tangent bundle).

Comment: Do we need exceptional collections to see this, or is it an elementary fact?

Comment: This can also be proved without using exceptional collections, but not as easy.